# random number generator related question

Tags: c++, random

So here's the code:

```
if(rand_s(&number) != 0) cout << "Random number generator failed!" << endl;
```

Question is - does it mean that the program outputs a failure message every time the random number generated with this `rand_s(&number)` expression is greater than zero? And if so, why would i want such a thing?

```
// complete code

unsigned int number = 0;

cout << "Random values are:" << endl;
double max = 1000000.0;

for(int i = 0 ; i<100 ; i++)
{
   if(rand_s(&number) != 0)
   cout << "Random number generator failed!" << endl;

   number = static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<double>(number)/UINT_MAX*max)+1;

   // output
   cout << setw(12) << number;
   if((i+1) % 5 == 0) cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Googling for `c++` and `rand_r` (--> third result on google for me: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxtz2fa8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) would have been much less work than opening a full question here.

Comment: i believed that rand_s returns a random value, that is why i was confused in the first place

Comment: It seriously improved my own productivity to always look up the manual of something or googling it first. I think your question is a good example for the reason ;) Of course, sometimes google and the manual are too hard, outdated, or something; then is the time to come here :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No rand_s returns an `errno_t` so 0 means there was no error. Anything else is indicating that there was an error when running the function.

More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxtz2fa8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

No. [here is the link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxtz2fa8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
rand_s return value: Zero if successful, otherwise, an error code.
```

Your random value will be: *number*

Answer (score 1):

The return value of function is 0 if the function execution completes successfully. The result is stored in number. Note that you are passing by address.